# Remove files and folders older than x days on windows

Tags: windows-xp

How to remove files/folders older than x days on windows from command prompt?

Comment: Install `cygwin` then ask the same question, but for Linux instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use forfiles in Windows 2003, Vista and Seven, for example for deleting files older than 3 days :

```
Forfiles -p "<path>" -s -m *.* -d -3 -c "Cmd /C del @FILE"
```

or you can do the same thing with powershell :

http://www.networknet.nl/apps/wp/published/powershell-delete-files-older-than-x-days